# pointer arithmetic in C while working with array

Tags: c, pointers

**CASE 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
    char *p;
    p = (char*) arr;
    printf(" %p - %d\n",&p, *p);
    p = p+1;
    printf("%p - %d\n",&p, *p);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0x7ffde540b000 - 2  
0x7ffde540b000 - 0
```

In above code value of pointer 'p' is increased by 1 - but address doesn't changed.

Again I increased the value of p by 4 (i.e p = p+4).
This time I get the following output -

```
0x7ffe50a2dff0 - 2  
0x7ffe50a2dff0 - 3
```

pointer move to the location arr[1] and prints the correct value.

but address doesn't changed.

**CASE 2:**

Now rewritten the above code (removed '&' from print statement)

```
printf(" %p - %d\n", p, *p);
p = p+1;
printf(" %p - %d\n", p, *p);
```

output -

```
0x7ffdb20b9d1c - 2  
0x7ffdb20b9d1d - 0
```

address changed by 1.

and similarly it works correctly when I update the code with p = p+4;
Output -

```
0x7ffef8735d6c - 2  
0x7ffef8735d70 - 3
```

Address increased by 4.

I am not getting why address is not changed, when I am using '&' in print statement (CASE I).
What is difference between '&p' and 'p' in this case.

OS is Kubuntu and compiler GCC.

Comment: Note that `%p` requires a `(void *)`. If you don't cast it to that type, the result is undefined behavior.

Comment: This might seem sarcastic, but what you really need is an understanding of pointers, addresses and the involved operators. Your code is almost tailor made to learn about all of that. Get a book, do more tutorials, it will become clear.

Comment: And asking a question which is basically asking for such a fundamental explanation is asking for a tutorial, which I am sorry to say, is off-topic. This is not about "so simple, you show know". It is about "so long an answer and so unspecific".

Comment: The &p is the address in memory where the variable p is stored (located).  Adding to p does not change its address, just its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` is a variable of type `char *`

as a `char *` variable `p` holds values which represent pointers to characters.

`&p` is the address where this variable `p` is stored in memory.

When you write `p = p + 1` you change the value of the variable `p`. But the variable `p` is the same variable, stored at the same memory, so naturally `&p` doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

the &-operator in c gives you the adress where the value is stored. so with `&p` you get the address where `p` is stored and NOT the adress of the value `p` points to. whichs is why the adress in your first case did not change. 
case 2: you removed the `&` so you get the value of the adress where `p` points to which changes once you increase `p`.

i hope this is clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not what you are doing, but how you are printing the data.

```
int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
char *p = (char *) arr;

printf(" %p - %d\n", p, *p);
p = p+1;
printf("%p - %d\n", p, *p);
```

If you substitute the apparitions of `&p` by just `p`, then you'll get the results you expected. The problem is that `&` is read as "get the address of", so `&p` will return the address in which `char * p` is stored, ¡and that never changes!

```
int arr[3] = {2,3,4};
int *p = arr;

printf(" %p - %d\n", p, *p);
p = p+1;
printf("%p - %d\n", p, *p);
```

That's why your second block of code works. And just above these lines you have something which actually makes more sense, in which `p` is an `int *`.

I suggest you take a look at [C-Sim](http://jbgarcia.webs.uvigo.es/prys/csim/) (disclaimer: it was created by me), and follow the tutorials. C-Sim will draw a status diagram for code such as the one above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should (must) add `(void *)` casts to all `%p` conversions.